# How get all metadata tables in iceerg?

Tags: apache-spark, trino, apache-iceberg

Iceberg specification defined a list of [metadata tables](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-queries/#inspecting-tables):

- history
- metadata_log_entries
- snapshots
- files
- manifests
- partitions
- all_data_files
- all_data_files
- all_manifests
- refs

But `metadata_log_entries` is not found while `properties` can be selected but not mentioned in the documentation. Is there a way to select all metadata tables? May be all for some table like `select * from datalake.my_db.my_table$metadata_tables`?